# How to remove particular key in Firebase using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove first key and its value. Like for example, in this image:

[image]

How can I modify or remove a specific key in the database of `console.firebase.google`?

Answer (score 0):

i think it will solve your issue.

```
Firebase *ref = path to the parent node
[ref setValue: nil];
```

Comment: Don't you need a `forKey:` parameter?

Comment: @Ferrakkem thanks, but the above you mention will delete all the values, i want to remove the first key only. How can i do that??

Comment: @Droppy , Frrakkem actually my question is to update the specific field in Firebase, Will you please tell me how can i do that??